# Best solution to prevent Brute Force Attacks in a web application with a login form

Tags: security, web-applications, brute-force

I am making a web application when users login inserting their username and password in a form. I have been reading about brute force attacks and brute force attacks prevention, but it seems there is not an optimal solution the prevent them.

Locking accounts after some wrong attempt could enable a person (a badboy) to freeze another person's account for a X time.

Using captchas after Y failed attemps is not also a good solution, because is easy to bypass them.

Adding a delay could slow a single-threaded attack, but not multi-threaded attack(the attacker sends multiple simultaneous authentication requests).

But then I say, sites like facebook, twitter, gmail are not hacked using brute force so easily. So I wonder how the do to prevent it.

I would like to know your opinions and advices (based on experience) about how to prevent this kind of attacks?

Comment: Rule #1: Don't give verbose message errors. Only say `Username And/Or Password is invalid` and nothing like `Username is correct however password is invalid`.

Comment: It is really unclear what types of attacks you are worried about. You also make statements like CAPTCHAs are "easy to bypass". I'm uncertain that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, ya. Tell us your threat model first, buddy. Are you trying to prevent brute force by someone with unlimited funds, hardware, and IP addresses? And lemme guess, you only have a AWS Micro instance...

It is not easy to defeat CAPTCHA, especially ReCAPTCHA, and it still requires work/time by the attacker. By definition ReCAPTCHA cannot be OCR'd.

If you don't like CAPTCHA, require Proof of Work. Make the user agent calculate the prime factors of a real big number. Sure, they could use thousands of computers, but that costs a lot of money.

Use a slow hash algorithm on fast servers. BCrypt with a factor of 12 is nice and slow, and you can always increase that, and run it on your own GPUs. Make sure you use a random salt, so that the attacker can't pre-calculate hashes of common passwords.

Encourage your users to use long, complex passwords.